# Cannot start function in "document.write();"

Tags: javascript, image, web, document.write

I'm new to JavaScript. 
I've already used Java and C# (and a bit of c++)

So far..

I'm using JavaScript to load pictures from a directory into an Array. After this I want to place this pictures on my page.

This works already.

The next step was to add a fullscreen function, to load the picture in fullscreen resolution.

```
var myfiles; 
var pfad = "./bilder/"    //directory of the images
var index = 0;

myfiles = new Array(); //String array with the names of the pictures
myfiles[0] = "01.png"; 
myfiles[1] = "01.png"; //usw. 
myfiles[2] = "03.png";
myfiles[3] = "02.png";


function fullScreen(bild) {
    document.write('<img src="'+ pfad + bild + '" border="0" width="100%">'); 
    alert (bild);
}

function start() {
    for(var i=0; i < myfiles.length; i++) { 
        pics[i].src = pfad + myfiles[i];
        string = myfiles[i];

        document.write('<img  onclick="fullScreen(string);" src="'+ pfad + myfiles[i] + '"     border="0" height="150px" >'); 
    } 
}
```

This code only loads the last picture of my array..
The function `fullScreen()` seems to take only the last value of string.

The HTML part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    start();
</script>
```

Comment: Calling `document.write()` after the page has loaded is asking for trouble. See [Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/464709).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi He didn't do it after dom ready   / window load. as long he is using it BEFORE dom ready , it would be fine.

Comment: @Royi, what do you mean? `fullScreen()` is called on click, after the document has loaded.

Comment: @RoyiNamir `start()` will be executed decently, but the click handler it writes to the document, also uses `document.write()`...

Comment: @Teemu Didn't notice this. if so , ignore my comment. certainly not to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only evaluating `string` when it is clicked, when the loop has already finished.

You'll need to pass it directly:

```
    for(var i=0; i < myfiles.length; i++) { 

    pics[i].src = pfad + myfiles[i];
    string = myfiles[i];

    document.write('<img  onclick="fullScreen(\''+string+'\');" src="'+ pfad + myfiles[i] + '"     border="0" height="150px" >'); 

    }
```

Comment: @James no it won't. It'll then be evaluated.

Comment: @Teemu true, but that's a different issue.

Comment: @Scimonster actually stringify will cause it to fail because it will wrap the string in double quotes resulting in `onclick="fullScreen('"01.png"');"`

Comment: @James Then how would you say to fix it? Maybe escaping?

Comment: Need to escape single quotes around the filename, my first comment was wrong too (going to delete it).  `onclick="fullscreen(\'' + string + '\');"` works

Comment: Another question: What does the + mean? Does it man that fullscreen(); should use string directly?

Comment: @user3680233 + is the JS concatenation operator.

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/dayewa/1/edit)**

JS

```
var myfiles = []; 
var pfad = "http://placehold.it/350x250/&text=";
var index = 0;

myfiles[0] = "Image 0"; 
myfiles[1] = "Image 1";
myfiles[2] = "Image 2";
myfiles[3] = "Image 3";

function fullscreen(){
  if(this.className == 'fullscreen') this.className = '';
  else this.className = 'fullscreen';
}

function createImage(src){ 
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = pfad + src;
  img.addEventListener('click', fullscreen);
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  return img;
}

function start(){
  for(var i=0; i < myfiles.length; i++) { 
    var img = createImage(myfiles[i]);
  } 
}
start();
```

CSS

```
html, body, .fullscreen {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the eventhandler. I'll give it a try !